# C++ standard lib equivalent of string::compare for numbers

Tags: c++, comparison, std

I come to C++ from Java, where I'm used to having compare functions that return a negative, zero, or positive int value to denote less than, equal to, or greater than.

In C++, I see that [string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) does this for strings, but I can find no such equivalent for numbers. Is there really nothing? Of course it's easy to implement myself, for example for doubles:

```
int compare_double(double d1, double d2) {
  return d1 < d2 ? -1 : (d1 > d2 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

But surely the standard library has something similar already and I'm just failing to find it?

Comment: I think that operator overloading is the norm.

Comment: The spaceship operator looks like it will likely be in C++20, so `d1 <=> d2` soon.

Comment: A common term for this kind of comparison is "3-way comparison"

Comment: Not arguing that it's useless, but am curious - what specifically do you want to use the function for?